# In multistep form, how to store value of previous step when user select an option in the next step?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple multistep where

Step1 = 1 input field for first name

Step2 = 2 radio options

Step3 = 3 radio options

Problem is when I am in step2 and have selected an option, that option is getting unselected when I select a radio option in Step3.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different name attribute of each radio group - radiobuttons do unselect all radiobuttons with the same name when selected.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Yes I found that I gave same name attribute to all radios. And on changing it is working properly now without getting deselection when in the next step.